# Trying to convert tiff+tfw to mbtiles. Projection issues?

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff, mapping

I have quite a number of huge TIFF files, each TIFF file has a TFW file associated. `gdalinfo` shows that the TIFF files are not real GeoTIFF (no embedded data). I know the TIFF's are in `WGS84, UTM` format. I was able some time ago to load these files into CompeGPS, which created properly calibrated images in that software.

Now I need them converted to MBTILES to use with AlpineQuest on Android. 
I can create the mbtiles with this command:

```
gdal_translate test.tif test.mbtiles -of MBTILES
```

The problem is that the map is not correctly calibrated!

It should sit around 45N/7E, but if I open the MBTILES in QGis or in AlpineQuest I see it around 40N/1E.

I suspect the problem is with the source image, since also the TIFF+TFW will create a similarly misplaced image in QGis.

Now I am quite an amateur in GIS matters, so I am puzzled and really don't understand what I am doing wrong or what I should be actually doing?

Can somebody help me undestand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `gdal_translate` what projection your input/output data is in (since it can't work it out as there are no `.prj` files. To do this you use the [`-a_srs`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) option with the EPSG code of your data.

You can use [epsg.io](http://epsg,io) to look up the EPSG code if you don't know it.

Comment: Yes! That was it. The difficult part for me was find the right code, since i had no precise idea. It turns out it is the EPSG:7791!